# How to draw half a pixel in C#?

Tags: c#, image, graphics, bitmap, bitmapimage

I work with bitmap images in pictureBoxes, and color some pixels. I wonder if it is possible to fill just half of pixel? If yes, how to perform it in C# ?

Comment: Would you please clarify what you mean by filling half of a pixel? What is the expected result?

Comment: "Filing half a pixel" doesn't make any sense. The pixel is the base unit for a bitmap. It would be like asking how to fill half a bit.

Comment: the closest thing you can do to "filling half a pixel" is use floats like, graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, new RectangleF(0f, 0f, .5f, .5f)

Answer (score 4):

You can't set color of just half of a pixel in bitmap.

You may be looking for [sub-pixel rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering) where RGB colors of individual pixels on a LCD screen are adjusted separately or [anti-aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing) where the color of pixels of single object essentially bleeds to nearby pixels to provide smoother edges.